# Science fiction novel about a drug that causes emotional/physical ecstasy by destroying memories

Tags: story-identification

The sci-fi mystery novel (which I obtained through the SFBC) came out in the mid-80s, and seemed to me to be the author's reaction to both AIDS and 80s MDMA-fueled club-scenes. The 'drug' itself was some kind of engineered virus or nano-robot, and may have been sexually transmittable. Individuals progressed through ecstasy to torpor and a vegetative state as memories were consumed.

The title of the book was something like "Harmony" or "Honor" and the SFBC version had a disco ball on the cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A Death of Honor](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1911165.A_Death_of_Honor), (1987) by Joe Clifford Faust

[image]